# The Pioneer Anomaly - A simple interpretation of J.D. Anderson’s paper please

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, newtonian-gravity

Although many believe the [Pioneer anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pioneer_anomaly) was resolved by Slava Turyshev in 2012. He believed the altered position of P10 was due to the potential thermal recoil effect from the RTG’s (the small nuclear powered units that supplied electricity to the craft). There are still doubts cast about a number of issues arising from his explanation. One being that the outset of the anomaly was not witnessed until the craft had passed Jupiter. This does not fit neatly with the RTG’s being responsible.

J.D.Anderson the former head of NASA’s investigation into the anomaly also questions Turyshev’s explanation. In his paper (1506 08070 ) [On the possible Onset of the Pioneer Anomaly](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.08070) (2012), he questions the thermal recoil theory and proposes an alternative option, although admitting there are also unanswered questions arising from that.

Can anyone in laymens terms explain to me what he is proposing in the paper above please?

Comment: From Jupiter outward is a much longer lever arm for a small perturbation to act on…

Comment: Your link is broken due to stackexchange formatting. I believe you meant https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.08070 . Hint for future questions / answers : Do not directly cut and paste queries from google.com (or its non-US affiliate sites). The result is a mess if you do. Instead open link and copy that page's address.

Comment: O.K. Thanks for the tip